# using tpu in custom training job on vertex ai

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vertex-ai, google-ai-platform

I try to use tpu-v2-8 through custom training job. My job runs fine on vm, but as custom training job, it OOM and also seems slower. It is also quite hard to schedule (pending for more than a few minutes, hit internal error most of the time, tried us-central1 and asia-east1).

Furthermore, the monitoring for cpu, memory, network etc exists in web the UI but says unavailable. Also, I'm using TF/JAX and the log format conforms to glog standard, yet the logging from my application all shows up as error instead of at appropriate levels in cloud logging.

Am I missing something or doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

No, everything seems fine on your side. To be specific:

- It makes sense that the training process is slower, as all operations are passed through Vertex AI to TPU.
- Sometimes, it's hard to obtain TPUs via Vertex AI. This could be the capacity issue in the Vertex AI itself. Just keep trying different regions, including `europe-west4`.
- Yes, unfortunately, no metric is available using TPU at this moment, and some log entries are marked as errors.

Comment: "all operations are passed through Vertex AI to TPU" I can understand logging agent etc adds some overhead, but (why) does all operations pass through vertex AI to TPU? Even read/write from gcs?
I have something working on tpu vm. It uses a lot of CPU memory, but it's like 2/3 of the total available CPU memory. I read that docker adds a little overhead, so I was surprised to see it OOM and much slower on vertex ai. Any tips on debugging or making it work? Will vertex ai pipeline with kubeflow work better than custom training job in this regard?